# Does the inequality $I(n^2) \leq 2 - \frac{5}{3q}$ improve $I(q^k) + I(n^2) < 3$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Denote the *abundancy index* of the positive integer $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$, where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.

Here is my *initial* question:

> Does the inequality $I(n^2) \leq 2 - \frac{5}{3q}$ lead to an improvement to the upper bound $I(q^k) + I(n^2) < 3$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

**MOTIVATION**

Here is a [proof](https://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) that $I(n^2) \leq 2 - \frac{5}{3q}$ holds in general.

Suppose to the contrary that $I(n^2) > 2 - \frac{5}{3q}$ is true.

Note that
$$I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} = \frac{2q^k (q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1} = 2 - 2\cdot\Bigg(\frac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1}-1}\Bigg),$$
so that we have
$$I(n^2) > 2 - \frac{5}{3q} \iff 2 - 2\cdot\Bigg(\frac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1}-1}\Bigg) > 2 - \frac{5}{3q} \iff \frac{5}{3q} > 2\cdot\Bigg(\frac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1}-1}\Bigg) \iff 5q^{k+1} - 5 > 6q^{k+1} - 6q \iff 0 > q^{k+1} - 6q + 5,$$
which then implies that $k=1$.  (Otherwise, if $k > 1$, we have
$$0 > q^{k+1} - 6q + 5 \geq q^6 - 6q + 5,$$
since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, contradicting $q \geq 5$.)  Now, since $k=1$, we get
$$0 > q^2 - 6q + 5 = (q - 1)(q - 5),$$
which implies that $1 < q < 5$.  This contradicts $q \geq 5$.  This concludes the proof.

Now, let $Q = 2 - \frac{5}{3q}$.

Since $I(q^k) < I(n^2)$, then we obtain
$$I(q^k) < I(n^2) \leq Q \iff (I(q^k) - Q)(I(n^2) - Q) \geq 0$$
$$\iff 2 + Q^2 = I(q^k)I(n^2) + Q^2 \geq Q(I(q^k) + I(n^2) \iff I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq \frac{2}{Q} + Q.$$
But $\frac{2}{Q} + Q$ can be rewritten as
$$\dfrac{2}{Q} + Q = \dfrac{2}{2 - \dfrac{5}{3q}} + \Bigg(2 - \dfrac{5}{3q}\Bigg) = 3 - \Bigg(\dfrac{5}{3q} - \dfrac{5}{6q-5}\Bigg) = 3 - \dfrac{5(3q - 5)}{3q(6q - 5)} = \dfrac{54q^2 - 60q + 25}{3q(6q - 5)}.$$

Let
$$f(q) = \dfrac{54q^2 - 60q + 25}{3q(6q - 5)}.$$
Then the derivative
$$f'(q) = \dfrac{5}{3q^2} - \dfrac{30}{(6q - 5)^2}$$
is **positive** for $q \geq 5$.  This means that $f$ is an **increasing** function of $q$, which implies that
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq \dfrac{2}{Q} + Q < \lim_{q \rightarrow \infty}{f(q)} = 3.$$

**FINAL QUESTION**

> Can we do better?  If that is not possible, can you explain why?

Comment: FYI, I got $I(n^2)\leqslant R\leqslant Q$ where $R=2-\dfrac{9q}{5q^2+10}$ but still $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\leqslant Q'\leqslant \dfrac 2R+R\leqslant \dfrac 2Q+Q$. It might be possible to find a better upper bound of the form $2-\dfrac{g(q)}{f(q)}$ where $\text{deg}(g(q))+1=\text{deg}(f(q))\geqslant 3$.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your proof for
$$I(n^2) \leq R = 2 - \dfrac{9q}{5q^2 + 10},$$
@mathlove?  Thanks!

Comment: One has $R-I(n^2)=\dfrac{q^{k+2}+20q^k-10q^2+9q-20}{5(q^2+2)(q^{k+1}-1)}$$\geqslant \dfrac{q^{1+2}+20q^1-10q^2+9q-20}{5(q^2+2)(q^{k+1}-1)}$$=\dfrac{(q-1)(q-4)(q-5)}{5(q^2+2)(q^{k+1}-1)}\geqslant 0$.

Comment: How did you figure out the value of $R$, @mathlove?

Comment: BTW, I think that is supposed to be
$$R - I(n^2) := f(k) = \dfrac{q^{k+2} + 20q^k - 10q^2 + 9q - 20}{5(q^2 + 2)(q^{k+1} - 1)} \geqslant \dfrac{q^{1+2} + 20q^1 - 10q^2 + 9q - 20}{5(q^2 + 2)(q^{1+1} - 1)} = \dfrac{(q - 4)(q - 5)}{5(q^2 + 2)(q + 1)} \geqslant 0,$$
since
$$f'(k) = \dfrac{2(q - 1){q^k}\log(q)}{(q^{k+1} - 1)^2} > 0$$
implies that $f(k)$ is an *increasing* function of $k$, so that $f(k) \geq f(1)$.

Comment: Let $g(k)=q^{k+2}+20q^k-10q^2+9q-20$ and $h(k)=5(q^2+2)(q^{k+1}-1)$. Since $h(k)$ is *positive*, al we have to prove is that $g(k)\geqslant 0$. So, it is enough that $R-I(n^2)=\dfrac{g(k)}{h(k)}=\dfrac{g(1)}{h(k)}\geqslant 0$.

Comment: I tried to find $a,b,c,d$ such that $\dfrac{2q^k(q-1)}{q^{k+1}-1}\leqslant 2-\dfrac{cq+d}{q^2+aq+b}\leqslant 2-\dfrac{5}{3q}$. This was very messy, so I set $a=d=0$, then I noticed $(b,c)=(2,\dfrac 95)$ works.

Comment: Might your method yield an upper bound for $I(n^2)$ better than
$$\dfrac{2q}{q+1},$$
@mathlove?

Comment: I don't know, but I cannot prove that it is impossible.

Comment: Okay, let me try, @mathlove.

Comment: I tried but was unsuccessful, @mathlove.  (Please see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4363111/28816).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long to comment* :

There is no such upper bound of the form $2−\dfrac{cq+d}{q^2+aq+b}$ better than $2−\dfrac{2}{q+1}$.

*Proof* :

Suppose that there is $(a,b,c,d)$ such that
$$2 - 2\cdot\dfrac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1} - 1} \leqslant 2 - \dfrac{cq+d}{q^2 + aq + b} \leqslant 2 - \dfrac{2}{q+1}$$

Then,
$$\dfrac{2q^k - 2}{q^{k+1} - 1} \geqslant \dfrac{cq+d}{q^2 + aq + b} \geqslant \dfrac{2}{q+1}$$
is equivalent to
$$\underbrace{\bigg((2-c)q^2+(2a-d)q+2b\bigg)}_{A}q^k-2q^2+(c-2a)q+d-2b\geqslant 0\tag1$$
$$(c-2)q^2+(c+d-2a)q+d-2b\geqslant 0\tag2$$

Suppose that $2-c\lt 0$. Then, it follows from $(1)$ that $A$ will be negative for a large $q^k$ and so LHS of $(1)$ will be negative. This is a contradiction. So, $2-c\geqslant 0$.

Suppose that $c-2\lt 0$. Then, it follows from $(2)$ that LHS of $(2)$ will be negative for large $q$. This is a contradiction. So, $c-2\geqslant 0$.

Therefore, we have to have $c=2$ for which we have
$$\underbrace{\bigg((2a-d)q+2b\bigg)}_{A}q^k-2q^2+(2-2a)q+d-2b\geqslant 0\tag3$$
$$(2+d-2a)q+d-2b\geqslant 0\tag4$$
It is necessary that $(3)$ holds for $k=1$, so we have to have
$$(2a-d-2)q^2+(2b+2-2a)q+d-2b\geqslant 0\tag5$$

Suppose that $2+d-2a\lt 0$. Then, LHS of $(4)$ will be negative for a large $q$. This is a contradiction. So, $2+d-2a\geqslant 0$.

Suppose that $2a-d-2\lt 0$. Then, LHS of $(5)$ will be negative for a large $q$. This is a contradcition. So, $2a-d-2\geqslant 0$.

Therefore, we have to have $d=2a-2$ for which we have
$$a-1-b\geqslant 0\tag6$$
$$(b+1-a)q+a-1-b\geqslant 0\tag7$$
Suppose that $b+1-a\lt 0$. Then, LHS of $(7)$ will be negative for a large $q$. This is a contradiction. So, $b+1-a\geqslant 0$.

Therefore, from $(7)$, we have to have $b=a-1$.

Now, since $b=a-1,c=2$ and $d=2a-2$, we finally have
$$2 - \dfrac{cq+d}{q^2 + aq + b}=2 - \dfrac{2q+2a-2}{q^2 + aq + a-1}=2-\frac{2(q+a-1)}{(q+1)(q+a-1)}=2-\dfrac{2}{q+1}$$

This means that there is no such upper bound of the form $2−\dfrac{cq+d}{q^2+aq+b}$ better than $2−\dfrac{2}{q+1}$.$\quad\blacksquare$

---

Similarly, one can prove that there is no such upper bound of the form $2−\dfrac{dq^2+eq+f}{q^3+aq^2+bq+c}$ better than $2−\dfrac{2}{q+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a partial answer.**

---

Note that
$$I(n^2) = \dfrac{2}{I(q^k)} \leq \dfrac{2}{I(q)} = \dfrac{2q}{q+1},$$
since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $k \geq 1$.

Following exactly the same steps in the original post, we obtain
$$I(q^k) < I(n^2) \leq \dfrac{2q}{q+1}.$$

[After working out the details](https://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-3-053-059.pdf), we get
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq 3 - \Bigg(\dfrac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)}\Bigg).$$

Set $Q' = 3 - \Bigg(\dfrac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)}\Bigg)$.

Let us compute the difference $Q' - \Bigg(\dfrac{2}{Q} + Q\Bigg)$ and determine its sign for $q \geq 5$.  We obtain

$$Q' - \Bigg(\dfrac{2}{Q} + Q\Bigg) = \dfrac{5(3q - 5)}{3q(6q - 5)} - \Bigg(\dfrac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)}\Bigg) = -\dfrac{(3q - 8)(q - 5)}{3q(q + 1)(6q - 5)} \leq 0,$$

with equality occurring if and only if $q = 5$.

This shows that $Q'$ is a better upper bound for $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$ than $\dfrac{2}{Q} + Q$.

---

In other words, $\dfrac{2}{Q} + Q$ is a **trivial upper bound** for $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$.

Comment: "Let us compute the difference $Q' - Q$" I think that you meant $Q'-\bigg(\dfrac 2Q+Q\bigg)$.

Comment: Edited.  Thanks, @mathlove!

Answer (score 0):

In this post, I will attempt to improve on the upper bound
$$I(n^2) \leq \dfrac{2q}{q+1}.$$

(Although this attempt is *unsuccessful*, I am retaining this answer here, mainly for my own benefit.)

---

Following [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967)'s lead in the comments, I tried to find $a, b, c, d, e, f \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$2 - 2\cdot\Bigg(\dfrac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1} - 1}\Bigg) = \frac{2q^k (q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1} \leq 2 - \Bigg(\dfrac{dq^2 + eq + f}{q^3 + aq^2 + bq + c}\Bigg) \leq 2 - \dfrac{2}{q+1} = \dfrac{2q}{q+1}.$$

This was very messy.  But these inequalities are equivalent
to
$$\dfrac{2}{q+1} \leq \dfrac{dq^2 + eq + f}{q^3 + aq^2 + bq + c} \leq 2\cdot\Bigg(\dfrac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1} - 1}\Bigg),$$
and I set
$$a = b = e = f = 0,$$
and then noticed that
$$(c, d) = (25, 2)$$
seems to work.

---

**PROOF**

Let
$$S = 2 - \dfrac{2q^2}{q^3 + 25}.$$

We compute
$$S - I(n^2) = 2\cdot\Bigg(\dfrac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1} - 1}\Bigg) - \dfrac{2q^2}{q^3 + 25} = \dfrac{2(25q^k - q^3 + q^2 - 25)}{(q^3 + 25)(q^{k+1} - 1)}.$$

Set
$$f(k) := \dfrac{2(25q^k - q^3 + q^2 - 25)}{(q^3 + 25)(q^{k+1} - 1)}.$$

Differentiating once with respect to $k$, we obtain
$$f'(k) = \dfrac{2(q - 1){q^k}\log(q)}{(q^{k+1} - 1)^2},$$
which is **positive**.  This means that $f(k)$ is an *increasing function* of $k$, which implies that
$$f(k) \geq f(1) = -\dfrac{2(q^2 - 25)}{(q + 1)(q^3 + 25)}.$$

This implies that
$$I(n^2) \leq S + \dfrac{2(q^2 - 25)}{(q + 1)(q^3 + 25)} = \Bigg(2 - \dfrac{2q^2}{q^3 + 25}\Bigg) + \dfrac{2(q^2 - 25)}{(q + 1)(q^3 + 25)} = \dfrac{2q}{q+1},$$
which **seems to show**, at least, for these particular values for
$$(a, b, c, d, e, f) = (0, 0, 25, 2, 0, 0)$$
that
$$I(n^2) \leq \dfrac{2q}{q+1}$$
is *best-possible*.

Comment: I think that I can prove that there is no such upper bound of the form $2 - \dfrac{cq+d}{q^2 + aq+b}$ or $2 - \dfrac{dq^2 + eq + f}{q^3 + aq^2 + bq + c}$ better than $2-\dfrac{2}{q+1}$. So, it seems that this method does not work.

Comment: That **is** totally cool, @mathlove!  Would you mind fleshing out the details for that proof in an actual answer?  Thanks!

Comment: I have written a proof that there is no such upper bound of the form $2−\dfrac{cq+d}{q^2+aq+b}$ or $2−\dfrac{dq^2+eq+f}{q^3+aq^2+bq+c}$ better than $2−\dfrac{2}{q+1}$.